FindInstance Not Stopping
I am trying to use FindInstance to find a solution to a system of equations. It does not return the empty set, but instead continues to run. Does this mean that there is no solution? Or perhaps I am not searching in a very efficient way.
Here is my code:
\[Tau] = 1;
n = 1;
\[Lambda] = Sqrt[421/100];
sol1 = FindInstance[
  a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0 && f > 0 && - 
     a^2 b^2 + (-\[Tau]^2 + b^2 + c^2) (-\[Tau]^2 + a^2 + e^2) == 
    0 && -e^2 f^2 + (-\[Tau]^2 + a^2 + e^2) (-\[Tau]^2 + d^2 + f^2) ==
     0 && -c^2 d^2 + (-\[Tau]^2 + b^2 + c^2) (-\[Tau]^2 + d^2 + f^2) ==
     0 && -b^2 c^2 + (-\[Tau]^2 + a^2 + b^2) (-\[Tau]^2 + c^2 + d^2) ==
     0 && -a^2 e^2 + (-\[Tau]^2 + a^2 + b^2) (-\[Tau]^2 + e^2 + f^2) ==
     0 && -d^2 f^2 + (-\[Tau]^2 + c^2 + d^2) (-\[Tau]^2 + e^2 + f^2) ==
     0 && (b*d*e) + (a*c*f) == \[Lambda]*\[Tau]^2, {a, b, c, d, e, f},
   Reals, n]

Maybe there is a hack to help Mathematica find a solution?

Try
\[Tau]=1;n=1;\[Lambda]=Sqrt[421/100];
sol=NMinimize[{
  (a^2 b^2+(-\[Tau]^2+b^2+c^2)(-\[Tau]^2+a^2+e^2))^2+
  (-e^2 f^2+(-\[Tau]^2+a^2+e^2)(-\[Tau]^2+d^2+f^2))^2+
  (-c^2 d^2+(-\[Tau]^2+b^2+c^2)(-\[Tau]^2+d^2+f^2))^2+
  (-b^2 c^2+(-\[Tau]^2+a^2+b^2)(-\[Tau]^2+c^2+d^2))^2+
  (-a^2 e^2+(-\[Tau]^2+a^2+b^2)(-\[Tau]^2+e^2+f^2))^2+
  (-d^2 f^2+(-\[Tau]^2+c^2+d^2)(-\[Tau]^2+e^2+f^2))^2+
  ((b*d*e)+(a*c*f)-\[Lambda]*\[Tau]^2)^2,
  a>0&&b>0&&c>0&&d>0&&e>0&&f>0},
  {a,b,c,d,e,f},
  WorkingPrecision->128,MaxIterations->256]
{(-a^2 b^2+(-1+b^2+c^2)(-1+a^2+e^2)),
 (-e^2 f^2+(-1+a^2+e^2)(-1+d^2+f^2)),
 (-c^2 d^2+(-1+b^2+c^2)(-1+d^2+f^2)),
 (-b^2 c^2+(-1+a^2+b^2)(-1+c^2+d^2)),
 (-a^2 e^2+(-1+a^2+b^2)(-1+e^2+f^2)),
 (-d^2 f^2+(-1+c^2+d^2)(-1+e^2+f^2)),
 (b*d*e+a*c*f-\[Lambda])}/.sol[[2]]

which quickly returns
{9.65362205967277478559797202718728880858762589393580177220...*^-86, 
 {a -> 1.58676914042148787600329667890460025781430437500068..., 
  b -> 1.73732923237367832290800656404896028440834446437409...*^-22,
  c -> 0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999997522042...,
  d -> 3.81610681460492018898952330106787394677622017494450...*^-22,
  e -> 1.00999659371200928503020331174304333216073121640139...,
  f -> 1.29308567995171570422578705866512956975129974016901...}}

and
{-1.251711563603472430912484510701155045533983700703725108...*^-43,
 1.5925776171116218504460913273520229480789565918734536137...*^-43,
 -1.586487672518437771569949982394361661617805406483608735...*^-43,
 1.1563170231703609986650576058361992856346436212759085595...*^-43,
 -1.592577617111621850446003398447808055045607339939354948...*^-43,
 -8.0936102506902750025539737313188498966186879665043384130...*^-44, 
 -9.681143291961894413486196940135453159653276161664539212...*^-64}

And you can bump the precision even higher if that is what you have to do

Thanks. So if I understand what's happening here, Mathematica is having a hard time dealing with $\sqrt(\frac{421}{100})$ (probably because 421 is prime so its square root will be irrational), so you're limiting the precision to get an actual answer out. What exactly is "MaxIterations" doing here? Also, for my particular purposes, it would be preferable to have an exact representation of the solution, say expressed as radicals. Is there any hope of accomplishing that?

Exactly why some part of some algorithm buried deep within MMA is having a hard time is usually difficult to ever know. FindInstance often impresses me that it is able to find something. I quickly tried Solve and then Reduce and neither gave me a quick solution. I then turn to NMinimize If you need an exact solution then try hammering on Reduce and see if there is any chance of getting what you need.

Okay. I appreciate the help!

Reals isn't necessary because you have already said everything is positive and that means real. You can change Sqrt[421/100] to Sqrt[421]/10 but neither of those seem like they will help much. You might search for GroebnerBasis and see if you can find anything that seems relevant. A lonely brain cell is poking me about using that for difficult solutions, but I don't know if that is relevant to this problem or not.
